# MomentJS plus Map deprecacted error

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use momentjs so I can format the date correctly, but I got this warning when I `console.log()` the result. Please see my code below:

```js
var selectedTargetDate = $('select').val();
var startDate = moment(selectedTargetDate.split(' - ')[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var endDate = moment(selectedTargetDate.split(' - ')[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

var getDaysArray = function(start, end){
   for(var arr=[], dt=start; dt<=end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
      arr.push(new Date(dt));
   }
   return arr;
};

var daylist = getDaysArray(new Date(startDate),new Date(endDate));

daylist = daylist.map((v) => moment(v.toDateString()).format('DD MMM'));

console.log(daylist);
```

```html
<div>

  <select>
    <option value="08/27/2018 - 08/31/2018">08/27/2018 - 08/31/2018</option>
    <option value="09/10/2018 - 09/14/2018">09/10/2018 - 09/14/2018</option>
  </select>

</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thats just a warning not an error.

Comment: Hi @null. I edit my question. Any answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MomentJS defaults to browser parsing when the date is not in ISO or RFC2822 recognized format, and it prints this warning as well. This doesn't mean that the date string won't be parsed.

But the caveat is that MomentJS relies on browser's date specific implementations for that, which is no consistent. So, it is always good to pass the format of the string as well, i.e. use `moment(date, format)` constructor instead.

```js
var selectedTargetDate = $('select').val();
var startDate = moment(selectedTargetDate.split(' - ')[0], 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var endDate = moment(selectedTargetDate.split(' - ')[1], 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
  for (var arr = [], dt = start; dt <= end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
  }
  return arr;
};

var daylist = getDaysArray(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));

daylist = daylist.map((v) => moment(v.toDateString(), 'DDD Mon DD YYYY').format('DD MMM'));

console.log(daylist);
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="08/27/2018 - 08/31/2018">08/27/2018 - 08/31/2018</option>
    <option value="09/10/2018 - 09/14/2018">09/10/2018 - 09/14/2018</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wait. I noticed something. The date is different. It's January, it should be August.

Comment: I've corrected it.

Changed this:



`daylist = daylist.map((v) => moment(v.toDateString(), 'DDD Mon DD YYYY').format('DD MMM'));`

To this:

`daylist = daylist.map((v) => moment(v.toDateString(), 'ddd MMM DD YYYY').format('DD MMM'));`